# How are multiple prior declarations resolved for a new declaration with extern?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

What should the third `x` refer to in:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static char x = '1';

int main(void)
{
    char x = '2';
    {
        extern char x;
        printf("%c\n", x);
    }
}
```

This arose in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52875353/298225), and:

- In Apple LLVM 9.1.0 clang-902-0.39.2, the `x` of `extern char x` refers to the first `x`, and “1” is printed.
- [GCC 8.2 does not accept this source text.](https://godbolt.org/z/krEurT), complaining: “error: variable previously declared 'static' redeclared 'extern'”.

C 2018 6.2.2 4 says:

> For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier **extern** in a scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is visible, if the prior declaration specifies internal or external linkage, the linkage of the identifier at the later declaration is the same as the linkage specified at the prior declaration. If no prior declaration is visible, or if the prior declaration specifies no linkage, then the identifier has external linkage.

Since there are two prior declarations of `x`, the condition of each of the following “if” clauses is true, the first for the first prior declaration, and the second for the second prior declaration:

- … if the prior declaration specifies internal or external linkage, the linkage of the identifier at the later declaration is the same as the linkage specified at the prior declaration.
- … if the prior declaration specifies no linkage, then the identifier has external linkage.

Clang’s behavior here is consistent with using the first clause, so that the third `x` has internal linkage and refers to the same object as the first `x`. GCC’s behavior here is consistent with using the second clause, so that the third `x` has external linkage and conflicts with the first `x`, which has internal linkage.

Does the C standard give us a way to resolve which of these should be the case?

Comment: Funny thing is, [clang V8](https://wandbox.org/permlink/53D9SwbwoFmWfNj9) complains about `char x = '2';` not being used (so it uses the static variable apparently. (Using C++ with [g++ V9](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uJhIa1j9daxq3KDv) the compiler will complain about both variables being unused and the linker throws a `undefined reference to 'x'` error :D)

Comment: I think the C11 note 31 which you didn't quote might be relevant. `For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier extern in a scope in which a
prior declaration of that identifier is visible,31)` where note 31 says `31) As specified in 6.2.1, the later declaration might hide the prior declaration.` This is the case here. 6.2.1 is the normal scope rules. In which case `extern` should refer to the local variable with no linkage.

Comment: @Lundin - I think that's the answer, and you should post is at such. The crux of the matter would seem to be the visibility of the `x` at file scope.

Comment: @StoryTeller The note itself isn't normative though, just guidance. I don't feel that I know this part of the standard well enough to give a definite answer.

Comment: So `extern` just goes up in scopes until it encounters an (any) identifier with the same name. That means `static char x` can never be reached.

Comment: @Lundin - The note isn't, but the last sentence in 6.2.1p4 is. *"Within the inner scope, the identifier designates the entity declared in the inner scope; the entity declared in the outer scope is hidden (**and not visible**) within the inner scope."*

Comment: I think Paul Ogilvie’s comment is on track: The passage starts “For an identifier… **in which a prior declaration of that identifier is visible**”. The prior declaration `char x` is visible, but the prior declaration `static char x` is not visible. So clang’s behavior would be wrong.

Comment: @Lundin: I have to figure the “later declaration” and the “prior declaration” in the note are the same “later declaration” and “prior declaration” as in the main text, and so they are not distinguishing the two prior declarations.

Comment: I'll add that p7 then declares the behavior undefined. So clang is not technically wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third declaration, `extern char x`, should declare `x` with external linkage, based on C 2018 6.2.2 4, which says:

> For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier **extern** in a scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is visible, if the prior declaration specifies internal or external linkage, the linkage of the identifier at the later declaration is the same as the linkage specified at the prior declaration. If no prior declaration is visible, or if the prior declaration specifies no linkage, then the identifier has external linkage.

At the declaration `extern char x`, the first declaration of `x` is not visible, as it has been hidden by the second declaration. Therefore, it does not qualify for “a prior declaration of that identifier is visible.” The second declaration of `x` is visible, so it is a “prior declaration” for the purposes of the above paragraph.

Then the last sentence should control: The prior declaration specifies no linkage (6.2.2 6, a block-scope identifier without `extern` has no linkage), so the third x has external linkage.

Then 6.2.2 7 is violated because the first `x` has internal linkage and the third `x` has external linkage:

> If, within a translation unit, the same identifier appears with both internal and external linkage, the behavior is undefined.

Since no syntax rule or constraint is violated, the C implementation is not required by the standard to report a diagnostic. Since the behavior is undefined, it may do anything, including accept this code and make the third `x` refer to the same object as the first `x`. Therefore, neither Clang nor GCC’s behaviors violate the standard in this regard. However, since 6.2.2 7 is violated, a diagnostic may be preferred, and its absence could be consider a defect of Clang.

(Credit to [Paul Ogilvie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3100312/paul-ogilvie) and [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c) for informing my thinking on this with their comments.)

Comment: IMHO it would be better to open the answer with the conclusion; the first paragraph seems to suggest the code declares `x` with external linkage (which it doesn't really since it turns out later the entire program is UB)

Comment: @M.M: Hmm, the statement that the third declaration should declare `x` with external linkage is the answer to the question, “What should the third x refer to in:…”. The notes about compiler behavior are add-ons. And the code must declare `x` with external linkage—that is what gives rise to the undefined behavior. If it does not declare `x` with external linkage, there is no undefined behavior, so the undefined behavior could not excuse the lack of this being considered an external declaration of `x`.

Comment: I still do not quite understand why GCC is saying that the first `x` would be redeclared to have external linkage. That doesn't make sense. If I declare the last `x` as having `external` linkage and this is referred to the first `x`, why should the first `x` then change its linkage? Isn't that kind of illogical?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio: The first declaration is `static char x = '1';`. The third declaration is `extern char x;`. If the `x` in the third declaration refers to the `x` in the first declaration, then the third declaration is a redeclaration of `x`. And it is a redeclaration of `x` with `extern`. That is what the GCC message says: “error: variable previously declared 'static' redeclared 'extern'”.

Comment: @EricPostpischil "*If the `x` in the third declaration refers to the `x` in the first declaration, then the third declaration is a redeclaration of `x`.*"- But that can't be at least fully correct. If the second declaration, here `char x = '2';` isn't present and with that the first declaration isn't hidden by the second, then it wouldn't redeclare `x` at file-scope. Instead, the third `extern` declaration of `x` would just refer to the `static` file scope variable, but not redeclaring `x` at file-scope.

Comment: Why is the linkage of the file-scope `x` modified when it is shadowed/hidden by the second declaration of `x` but not when referred to `x` at file scope directly (the second declaration is absent)?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio: Re “Why is the linkage of the file-scope `x` modified when it is shadowed/hidden by the second declaration of `x`…”: The error message does not say the linkage is modified. It says the `x` that was previously declared with “static” is redeclared with “extern”. “External” is a type of linkage. “extern” is a keyword. They are different things, although they are related. The message simply says there is a new declaration of `x` that has `extern` while there was a previous one that had `static`. It is not a great message since the actual reason the compiler is…

Comment: … complaining is not that `x` was redeclared but that the new declaration violates 6.2.2 7, as explained in this answer. Nonetheless, its statement that the new declaration has “extern” and a previous declaration has “static” is correct.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio: Re “Instead, the third extern declaration of `x` would just refer to the static file scope variable, but not redeclaring `x` at file-scope.” (a) What the third declaration would do if the second were missing is irrelevant; the compiler is allowed to treat the third declaration differently depending on whether the second declaration is present or not. When the second declaration is present, 6.2.2 7 is violated, and the C standard does not impose any rules on how the compiler handles the third declaration. (b) The statement you quote does not say…

Comment: … `x` is redeclared “at file-scope.” It merely says the third declaration is a redeclaration of `x`. That is true. There was an earlier declaration and a later declaration, so there is a redeclaration. Scope is irrelevant; we are just saying there is another declaration with the same identifier as a previous declaration.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ok, many things comes clearer now, Thank you. But another one "*What the third declaration would do if the second were missing is irrelevant*" - Well, it is of course technically irrelevant for your Q&A, but that is what I'm curious about and was object of [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62662937/) which was marked duped as of yours. --- Wouldn't 6.2.2/7 also be violated if the second declaration is absent as the third declaration would refer to `x` at file scope and the first declaration of `x` would be redeclared then by the third declaration, too?

Comment: Why does the shadowing of the file scope `x` only provide the GCC error of redeclaration/makes the difference?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio: If the second declaration is absent, C allows the `extern char x` declaration. 6.2.2 7 is not violated because 6.2.2 4 says the linkage resulting from `extern char x` is that of the prior declaration, so it `x` will have internal linkage from the original `static`. You can think of it as the `extern` here does not mean “external linkage”; it means “this declaration is referring to an `x` outside of—external to—this scope.” And that is fine when the `x` it refers to is the `static` `x`, because 6.2.2 4 says if the first declaration has internal linkage,…

Comment: … the `extern char x` declares `x` with the same linkage. But, when it refers to the non-`static` `x` in the second declaration, 6.2.2 4 says “If the prior declaration specifies no linkage” (which the plain `int a = 0` does) “then the identifier has external linkage.” In other words; `static int x; … extern int x;` redeclares `x` with internal linkage; the `extern int x` inherits the previous linkage, but `{ int x; … extern int x;` redeclares `x` with no linkage; the `extern int x` does not inherit the previous linkage. It uses external linkage, and that creates a conflict.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ahh, now I understand. That is very very complex thought and very hard to understand - at least for me. To repeat it for the sake of clarity --- 1.GCC "thinks" that the third declaration belongs to `static` declared `x` at the first declaration in the first step. --- 2. But since there is a second declaration at function scope which hides/shadows the first declaration at file-scope, GCC refers the third declaration of `x` to the second declaration at function-scope, which has no linkage. --- 3. As the second declaration has no linkage, the declaration of `x` has to be...

Comment: ....outside of the (function) scope and refers to a definition of `x` out of the function-scope, which it can't find with the first declaration since it is hidden by the second. So `x` in a generic point of view is redeclared from `static` to `extern`. --- But there comes another question: Why does GCC suppose that the third declaration of `x` would belong to the first declaration of `x` in the first place when it is hidden/shadowed by the second declaration? ....

Comment: This diagnostic gives the impression that GCC evaluates the third declaration before the second one. Or to view it from another point: Shouldn't the diagnostic of "*error: variable previously declared 'static' redeclared 'extern'”*" then come for first declaration at file-scope instead of at the third declaration? Or can't this be the case just because of the fact that the compiler reads the file from top to bottom and it can't know that `x`, declared at the first declaration with `static` is redeclared later in the following below code at that certain point of time?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio: My guess would be GCC was written to match an `extern` declaration to an earlier internal-linkage or external-linkage declaration because those are the only ones it can match without having undefined behavior. When there is an intervening no-linkage declaration, that matching is prevented. The error message reflects this design of GCC, rather than our deductions according to the rules. I also suspect the rules in the C standard were not fully designed but were retroactively adapted to fit historical behavior in assorted C compilers, so they are somewhat irregular.