# How to fix "variable previously declared 'static' redeclared 'extern' error"?

Tags: c, static, extern, linkage

When I try:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int c1 = 10;

int main(){

    {
        extern int c1; //c1 here still has internal linkage
        printf("%d",c1);
    }

return 0;
}
```

Nothing goes wrong. But when I try to modify it a little bit like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int c1 = 10;

int main(){

    int c1 = 20; //This is where I modified.
    c1++;

    {
        extern int c1;
        printf("%d",c1);
    }

return 0;
}
```

And suddenly, there's an error coming out. It says "variable previously declared 'static' redeclared 'extern'". Why?

Verbatim error message:

```
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:11:20: error: variable previously declared ‘static’ redeclared ‘extern’
         extern int c1;
```

Comment: cannot reproduce;

Comment: Why do you define c1 twice? static and with a scope of 'main'?

Comment: Both versions work for me in MSVC and print `10`.

Comment: compile with the `-Wshadow` flag, please if you are on `gcc`.

Comment: Please explain your intention of `int c1 = 20;`. What does the line do by your understanding, i.e. what do you intend that line to do? Or do you just change around and try what happens?

Comment: Don't do such things. That should fix it.

Comment: For me, the error is a linker error, which I can fix by changing `printf("%d", c1);` with `printf("%d", ::c1)`, which will print 10 and also warn me about the unused variable `c1` that is declared inside the `main()` function. `-Wshadow` would have warned about that anyways.

Comment: I think the question here is about understanding the error. Why is the compiler complaining that c1 was already declared as static in the second example, when it has no issue with it in the first. Clearly it has something to do with the c1 declaration in main shadowing the static global c1 declaration before the extern c1 declaration.

Comment: @JoeyMallone Wrong language. No :: in C.

Comment: @JoeyMallone Thanks. It turns out to be something about the gcc compiler.

Comment: I tried both on online C compiler and nothing went wrong. So I guess it is the compiler compatibility cause the problem. Thanks, guys.

Comment: Do not compile C code using a C++ compiler and wonder.

Comment: Per [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52876463/how-are-multiple-prior-declarations-resolved-for-a-new-declaration-with-extern), the behavior in this situation is not defined by the C standard. The C standard does not provide a way to refer to the outermost identifier after declaring a new identifier with the same name but no linkage; the new identifier hides the old one. Although GCC’s message is confusing, it does not violate the C standard, since the standard does not define the behavior.

Comment: To summarize: If you declare an identifier `static` (giving it internal linkage) and later declare it `extern` while the compiler can see the first declaration, the later declaration also has internal linkage, by a rule in the C standard. However, if the first declaration is hidden by an intervening declaration with no linkage, the later declaration with `extern` does not see the internal version and declares a new identifier with external linkage. Then we have an identifier with both external and internal linkage, which violates a rule in the C standard.

Comment: Regarding a fix: If you want to refer to the same `c1` in main, remove the `int` from `int c1 = 20`. If you want to refer to a different `c1`, the C standard does not provide a way to do this and also later declare `c1` with `extern`. Therefore, you must use a different name (which could be done by using the preprocessor to kludge the names without changing them in the source text, but that is bad practice and should be used only when compelled by circumstances).

Comment: @n.m., indeed! I overlooked the fact that this is `C` and not `C++`. Learned something new again, i.e. after renaming the file as `main.c` and compiling with `gcc`, I got the exact error that the OP got. Apparently, I should keep this in mind always _"
Do not compile C code using a C++ compiler and wonder. – alk 2 hours ago
"_